# JCR-SQL2 Filter Query to get only empty nodes

Tags: magnolia, jcr-sql2

I have the following JCR-SQL2-Query:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS nodes WHERE NAME(nodes) = 'NameOfTheNode'
```

Right now I get all the nodes with the name 'NameOfTheNode'. But I want to limit the results to nodes that are empty respectively have no child nodes.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE50/JCR-SQL2#JCR-SQL2-SinceModeShape4.0: it is not possible to query nodes with no children in JCR-SQL2:

> Additional dynamic operand "CHILDCOUNT(selectorName)" that enables
>   placing constraints on the number of children. Although there are
>   several ways to use it, this is especially effective for **finding nodes
>   with no children, which cannot otherwise be done in JCR-SQL2 (it is
>   not possible to use an anti-join with CHILDNODE join criteria)**.